# How to show memory usage in Netbeans?

Tags: netbeans, memory-management

I would like to know if there is an option in Netbeans (v. 6.9) to show its memory usage.

For example, how much got allocated to it and how much it has used.

Comment: If you're on Windows, you could easily monitor this in Task Manager...

Comment: yeah but i would prefer to see it from netbeans itself.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, right click on the toolbar in Netbeans and select 'Memory'.

In Netbeans 8 it can be found under "Performance".